# Unexpected Polymorphism Behaviour In Java if same method overloaded and overridden

Tags: java, polymorphism, overriding, overloading

I have been doing some changes in my project where I found some weird or rather I will say unexpected behaviour of Polymorphism in Java. I have replicated same behaviour in a Poc given below.

**1. CommonInterface.java**

```
package com.general;

public interface CommonInterface {

    public void getViews(String str);

    public void getViews(String str, Long id);

}
```

**2. GenericUtility.java**

```
package com.general;

public class GenericUtility implements  CommonInterface{

    @Override
    public void getViews(String str) {
        System.out.println("This is getViews (single param)from  GenericUtility");
        getViews(str, null);
    }

    @Override
    public void getViews(String str, Long id)  {
        System.out.println("This is getViews (multi-param) from  GenericUtility");
    }

}
```

**3. CustomUtility.java**

```
package com.general;

public class CustomUtility extends GenericUtility {

    @Override
    public void getViews(String str) {
        System.out.println("This is getViews (single param)from  CustomUtility");
        super.getViews(str);
    }

    @Override
    public void getViews(String str, Long id) {
        System.out.println("This is getViews (multi-param) from  CustomUtility");
        super.getViews(str, null);
    }

}
```

**4. Main.java**

```
package com.general;

public class Main {

    public static void main(String[] args) {
        GenericUtility utility = new CustomUtility();
        String str = "Random String";
        utility.getViews(str);
    }
}
```

After running Main.java , my expected output is

```
This is getViews (single param)from  CustomUtility
This is getViews (single param)from  GenericUtility
This is getViews (multi-param) from  GenericUtility
```

But output that I get is

```
This is getViews (single param)from  CustomUtility
This is getViews (single param)from  GenericUtility
This is getViews (multi-param) from  CustomUtility
This is getViews (multi-param) from  GenericUtility
```

I am not able to understand why `com.general.GenericUtility#getViews(java.lang.String)` is calling `com.general.CustomUtility#getViews(java.lang.String, java.lang.Long)`

Is this expected behaviour and what is it that I don't know ?

Thanks in advance.

Comment: You seem to understand why `utility.getViews(str)` calls `CustomUtility.getViews`. Then you should also understand why the call `getViews(str, null);` (equivalent to `this.getViews(str, null);`) in `GenericUtility` will call the implementation in `CustomUtility`. The same rules apply, after all.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Java uses runtime virtual dispatch for calls to instance methods (that is, those that aren't static). That still applies to calls to `this`; that's how, for example, an abstract class can define an abstract method `createResultObject` to be implemented by subclasses and use that method in its `doProcessing` method.

In your case, the object *is* a `CustomUtility`, so calls to `this.getViews(String, String)` are dispatched to `CustomUtility`, which then uses `super` internally.

Comment: Thanks, now I understood how it works. :)

Answer (score 0):

When `GenericUtility.getViews(String)` calls `getViews(str, null);`, the `getViews(String, Long)` implementation that will be invoked is `CustomUtility.getViews(String, Long)`.

That's because `CustomUtility` overrides that method too. Irrespective of where the method is called from (including the superclass), a call to an overridden method will cause the overriding implementation to run. The only thing that can change this is the subclass explicitly invoking the method using `super`.

So here's roughly what is happening:

1. `main` calls `utility.getViews(str);`, which causes overriding
   `CustomUtility.getViews(String)` to run.
2. `CustomUtility.getViews(String)` calls `super.getViews(str)`, which
   causes `GenericUtility.getViews(String)` to run.
3. `GenericUtility.getViews(String)` calls `getViews(str, null)`, which
   causes the *overriding* `CustomUtility.getViews(String, Long)` to run
   (contrary to what you expected)
4. `CustomUtility.getViews(String, Long)` calls
   `super.getViews(str, null)`, which calls
   `GenericUtility.getViews(String, Long)` to run.